# Partial sums of $\frac{\pi}{2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n\cdot n!\cdot (2n+1) }$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, pi, trigonometric-series

Recently, I have found a formula for $\pi$. That is $$\frac{\pi}{2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n\cdot n!\cdot (2n+1) }$$

However, the problem arises when you take the partial sums. For instance, 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{50000} \frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n\cdot n! \cdot (2n+1)} \approx 1.57294$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{100000} \frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n\cdot n! \cdot (2n+1)} \approx 1.57439$$

But $\dfrac{\pi}{2} \lt 1.5708$

In other words, it can't exceed $1.5708$. So, how can it have a sum of $1.57439$ after summing $10^5+1$ terms if the sign of the series doesn't alternate?

- All the calculations were performed by Wolfram|Alpha.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 1):

I think you made some mistake while calculating the sums on WolframAlpha

[here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bn%3D0%7D%5E%7B50000%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B(2n-1)!!%7D%7B2%5En%5Ccdot%20n!%20%5Ccdot%20(2n%2B1)!%7D) I calculated the first sum and it is equal to approx $1.08652$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{50000} \frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n\cdot n! \cdot (2n+1)!} \approx 1.08652$$

[Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bn%3D0%7D%5E%7B50000%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B(2n-1)!!%7D%7B2%5En%5Ccdot%20n!%5Ccdot%20(2n%2B1)%20%7D)

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n\cdot n!\cdot (2n+1) }\approx 1.57294$$

Here the sum is exceeding because of floating point approximations and you can never guarantee that WolframAlpha will always give you correct answers.

Comment: You don't have $(2n+1)!$ in the denominator, it's $(2n+1)$.

Comment: but in the question you have written it 2n+1!

Comment: @user591656: Your question actually has both $(2n+1)$ (in the stated formula) and $(2n+1)!$ (in the partial sums). :)

Comment: I have corrected it. Can you check it now?

Comment: @DeepeshMeena Where do I get to know more about floating point? Thanks, anyway!

Comment: wikipedia has a good article on it and you can always google you will easily find 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic

Comment: @user591656: For better accuracy, try clicking the "More Digits" button in WolframAlpha. I tried that, but got tired of waiting for the recalculation to finish. :)